# FPGA compilation in labview

Tags: compilation, fpga, xilinx, labview, xilinx-ise

I have a problem with FPGA compilation. I am using single board rio 9602.

I have installed:

- Windows 7 operating system
- LabVIEW 2015 sp1 (32bit),
- LabVIEW 2015 sp1 FPGA module,
- LabVIEW 2015 sp1 Real-Time Module,
- NI CompactRIO 16.0- NI CompactRIO Device Drivers August 2016
- LabVIEW 2015 SP1 FPGA Module Xilinx Tools 10.1 (ISE 10.1)

I configured sbRIO in NI MAX, then created a project. Everything looks ok, but
when i am trying to compile FPGA vi with local compile server i see the message:

,,LabVIEW FPGA:  The compile worker cannot perform the compilation. The compile worker may be configured incorrectly for this compilation or it may be in an error state."

What makes me confused, in details i see:
"Compiling on local compile server
Compilation Tool: Xilinx 14.7"
but i have never used Xilinx 14.7

I have no idea where I made a mistake and what i can do to solve this problem.
I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: Although I've never used LabView to build FPGA images, I would suggest using ISE 14.7 as that it's the latest version that support Spartan FPGAs.  Have you tried installing this?  [LabVIEW 2015 SP1 FPGA Module Xilinx Tools 14.7] (http://www.ni.com/download/labview-fpga-module-2015-sp1/5918/en/)

Answer (score 0):

First the 10.1 seems right, the 9602 is listed with ISE 10.1 : http://www.ni.com/product-documentation/53056/en/#toc1

Check in your FPGA Compile Worker window the versions installed [FPGA Compile worker window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9OT7.png)

Maybe you installed the 14.7 version by mistake with another installer and this could generate conflict, check version installed on your computer, uninstall if unused.
By the way you could now use the cloud which upload your vis and compile them on NI server, you don't have to worry about xilinx anymore.